# Suggestions for optimization library (constrained minimization) for use with Fortran

Tags: library, optimization, fortran

I am currently making the switch from Matlab to Fortran for performance reasons and I need some help finding a library that can help me with my minimization problem.

I am looking to minimize a certain non linair cost function. Lets say that `Ft = [x1 x2 y1 y2]` and my cost function is `Cost(Ft) = sum(Ft.^2)`. I also have several equality and inequality constraints. For example `sqrt((x1)^2 + (y1)^2) <= T` and `x1 + x2 = Xenv` in which `T` and `Xenv` are constants.

In matlab I am using fmincon and the SQP algorithm to find an optimum value for Ft that minimizes my cost function but also satisfies the constraints. At this point I am using a Langrange optimization scheme (solving linear equations with LAPACK) in Fortran, but that does not fit my needs concerning the constraints and limits the use of nonlineair costs functions.

I have also been looking at the Intel Math Kernel, but the functions included there do not allow non-lineair boundary constraints or inequality constraints.

Any help is much appreciated. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 if that makes any difference.

If anyone is interested, I am writing a thrust allocation algorithm for a Dynamic Positioning system for marine vessels. I have calculated the thrust needed from the thrusters to maintain position and now I need to allocate that thrust to the different thrusters in an optimized way (as less thrust per thruster as possible and not exceeding max thrust per thruster)

Comment: Writing out a Lagrangian is not an option, is it? IMSL and [NLOpt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) are quite decent. However, you should specify whether you are looking for a local or a global minimum. For further information, you can have a look at the [SciComp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: If possible I would like to find a global minimum every time within the constraints, although I get the impression that it is hard to verify that. I am now using the lagrangian, but that gives me problems with my non linear cost function and does not take into account (non linear) constraints... I will take a look at your suggestions, thanks!